# how do I code a two step calculator code in Python?

Tags: python, calculator

I want to build a two step calculator. Step 1: num1 + num2 > print result. Step 2 take printed result + num3. How do I code it so user has 3 initial inputs and the answer is used part of the following two user inputs?

This is my code, what do I need to correct?

```
num1 = float(input("Enter your first number: "))
op = input("Enter your operator: ") 
num2 = float(input("Enter your second number: "))
op2 = input("Enter second operator: ")
num3 = float(input("Enter third number: "))

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
    result = num1 + num2
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
    result = num1 - num2
elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
    result = num1 * num2
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
    result = num1 / num2
else:
    print("Invalid Operator")


if result == float and op2 == "+":
    print(result + num3)
elif result == float and op2 == "-":
    print(result - num3)
elif result == float and op2 == "/":
    print(result / num3)
elif result == float and op2 == "*":
    print(result / num3)
else:
    print("Invalid Operator")
```

The op2 input doesn't work or doesn't get me the result.?